# Convert CSS Box Shadow to iOS Shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Does anyone know how I can convert a `box-shadow` to a shadow on a UIButton in Objective-C?

For example this shadow:

```
box-shadow: 2px 0 0 0 #46d466,-2px 0 0 0 #46d466,0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 2px 8px 0 rgba(70,212,102,.7);
```

Answer (score 3):

`UIButton` have a special property layer of type CALayer.The layer property is great for many quick special effects, some built-in, like shadows are one of those built-in effects.

Please find the below code.

```
btn.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
btn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0);
btn.layer.shadowOpacity = 2.0;
btn.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
```

[image]

> 1. shadowOffset : The blur radius used to create the shadow. Defaults
>      to (0, -3).
> 2. shadowOpacity : The opacity of the layer’s shadow. Defaults to 0.
> 3. shadowRadius : The blur radius (in points) used to render the
>      layer’s shadow.
>
> For more information please review the API on [developer site](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer).

Or also you can change the offset of shadow.

```
btn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0);
```

[image]

You can also change the radius of the shadow which affects how blurry the shadow appears.

```
btn.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
```

[image]

Hope it will work for you!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 5, testBtn.frame.size.height);
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.8f].CGColor, nil];
    [testBtn.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

you can give whatever color or gradient.
hope this helps.

or

```
CALayer * bgLayer = [CALayer layer];
bgLayer.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 5, testBtn.frame.size.height);
bgLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
[testBtn.layer insertSublayer: bgLayer atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the button layer property. You can only assign one colour though (or use a gradient as suggested above) e.g.

```
button.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1.0);
button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
button.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0;
```